# Extending base schemas with Pydantic

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I'm building a FastAPI project, and in it, I'd like all my errors to be structured as such:

```
errors: {
    #... whatever  
}
```

I know I can create a pydantic schema as such:

```
class Error(BaseModel):
    error: Dict
```

However, for documentation sake, I'd like to avoid having to create two schemas every time I want to set an output response:

```
class AuthError(BaseModel):
    invalid_user = True

class Error(BaseModel):
    error: AuthError
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If what you need is a json containing anything there is no point to using pydantic since it's purpose is to map json structurs

Comment: @BastienB It's not arbitrary json objects. rather that each error object has the same wrapping structure.

Comment: check if this helps https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers creating a custom exception handler and json response..this is related to raising error, however it is not related to extending base schemas